# Sort articles depending on the users role that created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I'm trying to create a search result using [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

I have the results already done.

The users can create articles and each user has a role.

1. Regular
2. Privileged
3. Merchant

These roles are in a table called `UserRole`

I want to display the search results prioritizing the `Merchants` then the `Privileged` and finally the `Regular`.

**Articles Controller:**

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @roles = UserRole.all
  @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])

  # check if no search is made, it will show a blank page with search options only
  if params[:q].blank?
    @q = Article.none.ransack # so you have a ransack search
  else
    @q = Article.ransack params[:q]
  end

  # display results from search
  @articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**users schema**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  t.integer  "user_role_id",           default: 1
end
```

**user_role schema**

```
create_table "user_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "role_name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

**Question**

How do I display the search results prioritizing the `Merchants` then the `Privileged` and finally the `Regular`?

**edit**

**article schema**

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.float    "price"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
end
```

**almost solved**

changed

```
-    @articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('created_at desc')
```

to

```
+    @articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).joins(:user).order('users.user_role_id desc')
```

Now it is displaying the users who have role `3 Merchant` first and when they create a new article the new one goes to the top as well but if a `1 Regular` user creates an article it goes below the `2 Privileged` and `3 Merchant` users who have created an article.

But now when a new regular user registers, it will put the new articles below the old ones...

**SOLVED**

```
@articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).joins(:user).order('users.user_role_id desc', 'created_at desc')
```

`('users.user_role_id desc', 'created_at desc')`

Comment: What is the schema of `article` model ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the article schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it can be using an `order by` with `field` function.

```
@q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).joins(:user).order('FIELD(user_role_id,1,2,3) desc')
```

where 3 is Merchant role id , 2 is Privileged and 1 is Regular. The problem with this approach is that you are hard coding the Ids. This approach can be extended in several ways this is just a starting point.

PS: I am not familiar with ransack and not sure if the code above would work fine with it. The whole point is to illustrate the use of `Field()`

Comment: Hi, do I have to replace `Field` with something? I got `@articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('user_id(user_role_id,1,2,3) desc')` but it keeps saying `column "user_role_id" does not exist`. I added the `Articles` schema to the question

Comment: got it, I forgot to add the `joins` and did some changes. All I did was `@articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).joins(:user).order('users.user_role_id desc')` but the `1,2,3` is not working or I don't understand it... Thank you

Comment: just found out that when you have a new user registered, their articles will be put below the other ones...

Comment: sorry couldn't respond to your comments  ( TimeZone difference ) . Glad to here it is working , if it answers your question you can also mark it as correct.